# Where is the documentation on Android Compose component defaults?

Tags: android, components, documentation

There's a lot of info on Themes, styles, colours etc in Material 3, but nowhere can I find a list of Compose components and what they use for their defaults. I find this incredibly frustrating. I asked GPT-4 about this, but it was unable to shed light on it (which doesn't mean such info doesn't exist, of course). I just want to know what I have to change to do certain things, like changing the text size in a TextField. I should not have to set it explicitly in the params in every place I am using it. That's the idea behind themes - I should just be able to override the defaults in my Typography object. Here is what I asked GPT:

I want a list of the defaults. for instance, what is the default fontstyle for the text inside a OutlinedTextField? It's meaningless to provide themes and their styles and colours unless I know what the components are using! I should not have to experiment to find out what text style OutlinedTextField is using. I want a list that says:

```
OutlinedTextField: bodyMedium for the text, bodySmall for the supportingText...
Text: bodyMedium for the text...
etc.
```

Answer from GPT:

Finding a comprehensive list of default text styles for each specific Material Design 3 component in Jetpack Compose, like OutlinedTextField, is challenging. The official documentation does not explicitly list the default text styles for each component in a consolidated format. Instead, it provides information on how to use these components, their parameters, and customization options, including text styles.

Comment: The composables and their default parameter values are available in source code, readily accessible from within the IDE.

Comment: Thanks CommonWare. Yes, I am aware of that, but I should not have to trawl through source code to find these - especially as this is, as far as I'm aware, how theming should be done, and only special cases should require overriding the default in any given situation.

Comment: "only special cases should require overriding the default in any given situation" -- you are certainly welcome to your opinion. Personally, in a serious design system implementation, I would not rely on any styling defaults, lest those defaults change in some future version of Compose. Regardless, questions of the form "where can I find this off-site resource" are considered to be off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: It wasn't an opinion - I was merely voicing what I thought to be the case. I will take your recommendation to style everything as it seems logical. But saying "look in the source" makes me cringe - after 40 years in IT I now find that answer a cop out when people use it. As for my question - I rarely use SO to ask questions as I like to find my own answers, so I think I can be forgiven for one "off-topic" question. Happy new year to you.